# Migrating from Jersey 1 to Jersey 2 - How to deregister the filters added at WebTarget?

Tags: java, jersey, upgrade, jersey-2.0

We are doing a Jboss EAP7.2.6 Upgrade - JAX-RS migration and
Migrating from Jersey 1 to Jersey 2.

How to deregister the filters added at WebTarget ?

Whats the corresponding in Jersey2 for WebResource.removeAllFilters()/removeFilter().

Curently we are getting a Parse exception on Response and we did the below work around.

```
response.getHeaders().remove("Content-Type");
response.getHeaders().add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: There's no such thing in Jersey 2.x. Just create multiple WebTargets. Having multiple WebTargets for different purposes could add some code clarity.

Comment: thank you for the info.